# Add column with difference in days

Tags: powerbi

i'm trying the new Power BI (Desktop) to create a barchart that shows me the duration in days for the delivery of an order.

I have 2 files. 1 with the delivery data (date, barcode) and another file with the deliverystatusses (date, barcode).

I Created a relation in the powerBI relations tab on the left side to create a relation on barcode. 1 Delivery to many DeliveryStatusses.

Now I want to add a column/measure to calculate the number of days before a package is delivered. I searched a few blogs but with no succes.

The function DATEDIFF is only recognized in a measure, and measures seem to work on table date, not rowdata. So adding a column using the DATEDIFF function doesn't work.

Adding a column using a formula :

```
Duration = [DeliveryDate] - Delivery[OrderDate]
```

results in an error that the right side is a list (It seems the relationship isn't in place)?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You might try doing this in the Query window instead since I think each barcode has just one delivery date and one delivery status.  You could merge the two queries into a single table.  Then you wouldn't need to worry about the relationships... If on the other hand you can have multiple lines for each delivery in the delivery status table, then you need to get more fancy.  If you're only interested in the last status (as opposed to the history of status) you could again use the Query windows to group the data.  If you need the full flexibility, you'd probably need to create a Measure that expresses the logic you want.

Answer (score 0):

The `RELATED` keyword is used to reference another table. Update your query as follows and it should work.

Like this:

`Duration = [DeliveryDate] - RELATED(Delivery[OrderDate])`